# Sagemaker User Key and Secret for Machine Learning Process

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am working on one project which is combination of Node JS and React and express JS and we need Machine Learning implement in that for that we pass S3 Access key and Secret key for that but Linear Learner, Linear and Logistic Regression,Extreme Gradient Boosted Trees not working in process after process on data file in Machine Learning.We pass both sagemaker ll code image and sagemaker xgb code image,but even after that we can't get process of that three models and We need sagemaker User key and Sagemaker Secret and for that We don't know how to create that and not get any idea about that.

Can Any one Help me to start that processes ? using Sagemaker in AWS Machine Learning.